# Error after updating electron and changin nodeIntegration to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, electron

I recently went back to an old project and updated my electron version. I found online that electron now requires you to add in `nodeIntegration: true` in order to be able to import electron in your render process. I added this in as seen below, however, I am getting the following error after doing so and am unsure how to resolve this.

```
// Module Imports
const {app,BrowserWindow,dialog,ipcMain,remote} = require('electron')
var handlers        = require('./routelist.js');
var dns             = require('dns').promises;
var path            = require('path');
var Connection      = require('tedious').Connection;
var sql             = require('sequelize');
var axios           = require('axios');

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true},  width: 1730, height: 900, frame: false})
  win.loadFile('./render/index.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', function() {
  createWindow()
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:112)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:768)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68)
    at vendor-bundle.js:7033
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at createLoader (vendor-bundle.js:7032)
```

Let me know if I can provide further information.

Comment: Hi TJ, can you update your first code snippet to include everything in that file? Or if it's too large then just include the require statements and where `createWindow` gets called from.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I added in everything from the index.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> electron now requires you to add in nodeIntegration: true in order to be able to import electron in your render process

You cannot directly use `electron` in a renderer process, use `electron.remote`:

```js
const { remote } = require('electron');

const window = new remote.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
```

See https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This error occurs even if i remove any resemblance of an import statement from my renderer. It was fine on the previous version, however, I was getting a "require is not defined error" prior to adding in thenodeIntegration: true. I added that in and am now getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

After Using the chrome debugger for a really long time trying to locate when this error is happening it isn't related to electron in the slightest. The vendor bundle I am using is passing in an incorrect value for one of it's dependencies

Thanks to everyone for your time.